# Dart Flutter: throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a program for calculations in flutter and when building the package, it throws me to the "debyg.dart" file and points to the line "throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[". So what should I do with this error. I'm still new to flutter, so I don't know much.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'datchik/datchiki.dart';
import 'ThirdPage.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP10P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP50P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP100P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP500P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP1000P.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MyHome(),
        '/datchiki': (context) => SecondPage(),
        '/ThirdPage': (context) => ThirdPage(),
        '/TCP10P': (context) => const TCP10P(),
        '/TCP100P': (context) => const TCP100P(),
        '/TCP50P': (context) => const TCP50P(),
        '/TCP500P': (context) => const TCP500P(),
        '/TCP1000P': (context) => const TCP1000P(),
      },
  ),
  );
  }

  class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super (key: key);

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 162, 248),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
         Text("Главная страница",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          TextButton.icon(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
              foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white)
            ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/datchiki');
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: const Text('Датчики температур'),
          ),
  ElevatedButton.icon(
     style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
              foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white)
            ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/ThirdPage');
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                  label: const Text('ТСП - 50П')
                ),
        ],
        )
      ),
    )
  );
}
}
```

```
TCP-10P.dart The file in which the error appears
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'datchik/datchiki.dart';
import 'ThirdPage.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP10P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP50P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP100P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP500P.dart';
import 'datchik/TCP1000P.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
 MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   initialRoute: '/',
   routes: {
     '/': (context) => const MyHome(),
     '/datchiki': (context) => SecondPage(),
     '/ThirdPage': (context) => ThirdPage(),
     '/TCP10P': (context) => const TCP10P(),
     '/TCP100P': (context) => const TCP100P(),
     '/TCP50P': (context) => const TCP50P(),
     '/TCP500P': (context) => const TCP500P(),
     '/TCP1000P': (context) => const TCP1000P(),
   },
),
);
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
const MyHome({Key? key}) : super (key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
 backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 162, 248),
 body: SafeArea(
   child: Center(
     child: Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
      Text("Главная страница",
       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
       TextButton.icon(
         style: ButtonStyle(
           backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
           foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white)
         ),
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/datchiki');
           },
           icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
           label: const Text('Датчики температур'),
       ),
ElevatedButton.icon(
  style: ButtonStyle(
           backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
           foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white)
         ),
               onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/ThirdPage');
               },
               icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
               label: const Text('ТСП - 50П')
             ),
     ],
     )
   ),
 )
);
}
}
```

```
Debug.dart The file where it throws me

throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
        ErrorSummary('No Material widget found.'),
        ErrorDescription(
          '${context.widget.runtimeType} widgets require a Material '
          'widget ancestor.\n'
          'In Material Design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on '
          "a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that "
          'material is represented by the Material widget. It is the '
          'Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. '
          'Because of this, many material library widgets require that '
          'there be a Material widget in the tree above them.',
        ),
        ErrorHint(
          'To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly '
          'include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, '
          'such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.',
        ),
        ...context.describeMissingAncestor(expectedAncestorType: Material),
      ]);
```

I tried changing the SizedBox parameters, but nothing worked. Maybe I just did it wrong

Comment: You should share the TCP-10P.dart code.